# Is it MS Windows a GUI running over a 'core' OS?

Tags: windows, gui

As far as I know, the GUI of the linux distros runs over a non-graphic kernel. You can see the 'command prompt' loading programs and devices while the system starts. Moreover, you can do any task in the command prompt. I wonder if MS Windows is something like that, just a GUI running over a 'core' OS.

Comment: Why don't you ask Microsoft? If anyone's going to know the answer, they are.

Comment: This might be too great a generalisation, but you could consider "Windows" to be the "Windows Shell" and "Windows Kernel" tightly integrated. Which is in part why http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell#Shell_replacements is possible.

Comment: Have you tried reading a Wikipedia article or two?

Comment: Good software design principles frequently include decomposing the functionality required into separate components -- whether it be that of an operating system, application, or library/module.

Answer (score 7):

Windows 1.x, 2.x, 3.x ran on top of DOS, Windows 9x could be considered DOS-based, and the NT series, as well as XP, Vista, 7 and 8 have a command prompt for compatibility but do not "run on top of" anything.

Wikipedia has a good background:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Windows